# Add unique year from date to combobox

Tags: vba, date, excel, combobox

I have a list of dates in a column.  I want to add to a combobox on a userform the unique years from those dates.

The userform is there to generate a report based on a month and year the user selects.  I only want years that there have been entries made.  So when it goes to 2014, when the first entry is made into the spreadsheet for the year 2014 with be selectable for the report generator.

```
Dim c As Range, Coll As New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Sheets("Permits & Access").Range(ActiveSheet.Range("L3"), Sheet.Range    ("L3").End(xlDown))
Coll.Add c.Value, c.Value
Next c
On Error GoTo 0
For Each Item In Coll
cboYear.AddItem Item
Next Item
```

that is the code snippet i have used to display the unique dates.  But i actually only need the unique years.  I know to use the Year() method to extract the year, just not having any luck implementing it.

Comment: maybe you can change `Coll.Add c.Value, c.Value` to `Coll.Add Format(c, "yyyy"), Format(c, "yyyy")`? or if you're open to other approach, i posted an answer.

Comment: i am just trying the solution using the dictionary.  Just rejigging it to use the range that i need it to look at.  While doing that i saw your second comment and quickly gave that a go, but it wasn't returning anything.  I'm wondering if that is because it is reading the value as a string value and not as a date value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how i do it but using `Dictionary` instead.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim dict As Object, item As Variant
Dim cel, rng As Range

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A12") 

'--> empty ComboBox1
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""

'--> sort the range, sorting Collection or Dictionary is a bit complex
rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal 

'--> Test for unique year, add to dictionary
For Each cel In rng
    If Not dict.exists(Format(cel, "yyyy")) Then
        dict.Add Format(cel, "yyyy"), Format(cel, "yyyy")
    End If
Next

'--> Populate ComboBox1 with the unique year
For Each item In dict.items
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem item
Next

Set dict = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Actually i have noticed a glitch. In the spreadsheet, not all of the entries have a date for them.  So there are gaps in the date column.  When the form is run, it is moving the dates into chronological order and if there is a gap between dates moves the dates up to fill those gaps.

Comment: oh yes, it will not align with the rest of your data. what i suggest is copy the column with the date data in a temp location and do the sorting there instead. or you can include the entire range of data and then sort and then resize to rng to iterate on the dates column only.

Comment: Not the most prettiest of code to have to copy cells, but it works and that is the main thing.  Thanks.